# Display all rows when encountering NULL value

Tags: null, sybase

I use sysbase and I have a table here,

```
id type value
1   aa    11
2   bb    22
2   bb    22
2   dd    44
3   aa    11
3   bb    22
4   dd    44
```

and I just want to show it like :

```
id  aa  bb
1   11  
2       22
3   11  22
4
```

that is select out all  the "aa" and "bb" attribute for all the id, if the id doesn't have the aa attribute or bb attribute, just leave it as blank.
I think maybe union is useful for me to do that, but anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try. It might not be 100% the output you want, but it gives you a good start to work from.

You can also view this here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9eb8/1/0

```
SELECT
  P0.ID,
  ISNULL(MAX(P0.aa), '') as 'aa',
  ISNULL(MAX(P0.bb), '') as 'bb',
  ISNULL(MAX(P0.cc), '') as 'cc',
  ISNULL(MAX(P0.dd), '') as 'dd'
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ID,
    CASE type
      WHEN 'aa' THEN Value
      ELSE NULL
    END AS 'aa',
    CASE type
      WHEN 'bb' THEN Value
      ELSE NULL
    END AS 'bb',
    CASE type
      WHEN 'cc' THEN Value
      ELSE NULL
    END AS 'cc',
    CASE type
      WHEN 'dd' THEN Value
      ELSE NULL
    END AS 'dd'
  FROM
    blah
 ) P0
GROUP BY
  P0.ID
```